# The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid

Tags: javascript, phpbb, phpbb3, windows-live

I keep receiving this error from windows live

> The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not
>   valid. The expected value is
>   'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf' or a URL which matches
>   the redirect

Why do I keep receiving this error. I have the domain set in the windows live developer app

in the <head> element I have

```
<script src="//js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js"></script>
```

just below the <body> element I have

```
  WL.init({
    client_id: '{S_AL_WL_CLIENT_ID}', //{S_AL_WL_CLIENT_ID} = phpbb template variable for client_id
    redirect_uri: '{AL_BOARD_URL}', //{AL_BOARD_URL} = phpbb template variable for the  urlencoded domain name
    response_type: 'token',
    scope: ["wl.signin", "wl.basic", "wl.birthday", "wl.emails", "wl.work_profile", "wl.postal_addresses"]
});
```

the login button is

```
    <div id="login">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/windows_live_connect.png" alt="Windows Live" /></a> 
    </div>
```

the listener

```
jQuery('#login a').click(function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
            WL.login({
                scope: ["wl.signin", "wl.basic", "wl.birthday", "wl.emails", "wl.work_profile", "wl.postal_addresses"]
            }).then(function (response) 
            {
                //do something with stuff here. You know brainy type ajaxy stuff to auth a user
            },
            function (responseFailed) 
            {
                console.log("Error signing in: " + responseFailed.error_description);
            });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem turned out that [windows-live](/questions/tagged/windows-live) redirect_uri has to be exactly `http://www.yourdomain.com` and not `http://yourdomain.com`.
So if a user inputs `http://yourdomain.com` then this error will show but if a user has `http://www.yourdomain.com` then the script works.

I think I have been very spoilt with the Facebook Api.

So in the end I just made a regex to match against any url using the login button and force it to be www with .htaccess.

Comment: also adding `http://yourdomain.com` instead of `http://www.yourdomain.com` as the app domain @ windows-live app section allows use of both types of domain names but causes cookie errors.

Comment: i am facing the same problem, but my slug is dynamic each time, each time it varies, any solution please?